# Overlay multiple fviz clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to show several transparent overlaid "fviz_cluster" plots in one plot (of the same data):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dbscan)
library(factoextra)
d = cbind(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
# cluster the data (could be k-means, or any other method)
clus = dbscan(d, eps=0.2, minPts=5)
fviz_cluster(clus, data=iris,
             choose.vars=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),
             ellipse.type="convex", geom="point", show.clust.cent=FALSE)
```

[image]

```
# cluster again with different parameters
clus2 = dbscan(d, eps=0.3, minPts=5)
# How would I overlay the outlines and shading of the 'clus2' clusters
```

[image]

So what I would like is an overlay of these two plots. I'd change the colour palette of the second one of course. Is there a way to do this with fviz_cluster "off the shelf" or do I have to go into the internals? I'm surprised that fviz_cluster is supposed to be 'ggplot2-based' but doesn't allow layering of its plots, unless I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

### Crudely combined cluster

`fviz_cluster()` is happy to plot anything with `cluster` and `data` so you can crudely combine the data and plot it but this doesn't implement the outlier functionality, e.g.:

```
combined <- data.frame(cluster=clus1$cluster)
combined <- rbind(combined,
                  data.frame(cluster=ifelse(clus2$cluster > 0,
                                            clus2$cluster + max(combined$cluster),
                                            0)))
combined$data <- rbind(iris, iris)

fviz_cluster(combined,
             choose.vars=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),
             ellipse.type="convex",
             geom="point", show.clust.cent=FALSE)
```

[image: fviz_cluster() plotting two crudely combined clusters]

### Implement a dbscan merge

You could merge two or more `dbscan` objects by writing your own function but this probably won't look much better than previous example.

### Combine externally

ImageMagick can blend the images together and alter colours. I don't think this is going to work well because the points overlay and their appearance will change making legend incomplete, etc but here's an example:

```
convert AWRRa.png -modulate 100,100,120 \
    \( AN4Ng.png -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 70% +channel \) \
    -compose over -composite blended.convert.png
```

[image: The two plots from question combined with ImageMagick]

### Animation time!

A tangential answer to the question but worth exploring (depending on your medium) via [gganimate](https://www.ggplot2-exts.org/gganimate.html) or using ImageMagick to combine `ggsave()` frames, e.g.:

[image: ggplot png frames combined as an animated gif by ImageMagick]

### Multiple images

Giving up and going to multiple plots with [grid.arrange()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) is another option!

Comment: Thanks @kevin-j-walters - that was what I needed. I hacked together a fake dbscan object with all the points belonging to clusters (occuring multiple times if in multiple clusters) and then added all the non-belonging outlier to cluster=0 afterwards, so they are correctly shown as outliers.